# Where should I put this code, in react app

Tags: reactjs

I am following the react documentation on this link https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing.

it has an example of this code using node and express:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(9000);
```

to handle url like `domain.com/todos/42`.

when using `create-react-app` to generate react app. where should I put those code?

Comment: Please dont donwvote.. your too quick to judge.. I been looking many resource to fill up my understanding. but still lack.

Answer (score 0):

https://daveceddia.com/create-react-app-express-backend/

This is a good tutorial to help you with creating a react app with express

*updated link with correct one

Answer (score 0):

Actually you shouldn't put your code to react app. Because it's your front end part and node.js is your back end part.

So the best solution is you should call your request from react with "Ajax", "Axios" or etc.

Answer (score 0):

React or not your code should go in the 'build' folder (set in your code). You have to build your react app first, then move the contents from the 'build' directory of your React project to your server's 'build' directory.